# How do I sync with my Flickr Pro?

Tags: software-rec, backup, sync, photos

I have a [Flickr Pro](http://www.flickr.com/upgrade/) account and would like to sync it with all my photos. This is hoped to be a way to backup all my photos in an online repository.

So I need a tool that will watch a folder and then sync changes. I would love it if it kept sets up to date on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com) with the subfolders on my computer. I am not concerned with syncing tags, etc from Flickr.

I am happy to pay for it and I can use either a PC or a Mac. (I am using [Microsoft Live Sync](http://www.foldershare.com/) to keep the PC and the Mac the same).

Comment: I did start look into writing something that would do something a little like this, that would keep tags in sync, as well as geocoding. In the event that I get some free time to work on this, I'll try to remember to let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of this application can help you.

FlickrSync

- http://flickrsync.codeplex.com/

Flickr MetadataSynchr

- http://flickrmetadatasynchr.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think such a thing exists. The Flickr API doesn't really have the hooks (yet?) to make such a thing do-able w/o lots of work + requiring lots of internet traffic.

How would you keep Flickr metadata (tags, titles, descriptions) in sync? There isn't a local counterpart to a Flickr archive.

Comment: The very next answer provides two options which do precisely what you say isn't possible.

Comment: :shrug: I didn't say it isn't possible; I said I don't think such a thing exists. I guess there's stuff out there, I'm curious how much internet traffic it requires to keep things synchronized. (prob. a lot more than rsync)